# bootstrap-table - click on cell to load modal to edit

Tags: php, jquery, bootstrap-table

I'm using bootstrap-table and successfully load a table with filtering and paging.  I tried to add editing via x-editable but was not successful using the 3 together.

Next try is to click on one cell which would load a modal with any data in that cell, allow me to edit it, and save it.  I also need the "id" value of that row so I know how to save the data into a mysql db. Here is what I have tried:

```
  $('#myTable').on('click-cell.bs.table', function (field, value, row, $el) {
      if (value =="functionData"){
         alert($el.id+"-"+$el.functionData);
      }
  });
```

I get the id value of the row and the value of functionData which is good.  How do I load a modal windows with this data?  I've tried this:

```
  $('#myModal').hide();

  $('#myTable').on('click-cell.bs.table', function (field, value, row, $el) {
      if (value =="functionData"){
         alert($el.id+"-"+$el.functionData);
         $('.modal-body').local('content.html', function() {
            $('#myModal').modal({ show: true });
         });
  });
```

Eventually I want to load the data from the row I clicked on into the modal but first things first.

Comment: You need to share the relevant html code or try a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).